# 2 year old avocado plant not doing too great, possible cold damage

Tags: avocado, cold-weather

I have 2 avocado plants that are not doing too well...

Here is a photo:

[image]

About week ago they looked fine, a couple of dying leaves but nothing too bad.

In the last couple of days temperatures have started to go below -5 °C and the plants are outside in a small greenhouse.

As you can see the leaves are really limp and they started to go brown from di inside out, the tops are basically dried and i don't see any kind of rotting anywere.

Could this be cold damage?

And if it's even possible, how can i make the plants recover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be cold damage but it looks more like low humidity 
You should keep it indoors if you can with plenty of light and ensure the plant has all the humidity it needs.

It would be a good idea to check and make sure the roots are still alive as the frost would damage them. It could be game over

Comment: Ok, i'll keep it indoors and mist it with water. I don't think the roots died because of the frost since it was in the greenhouse but i'll check on them. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Your right the green house would stop the frost ,You might as well add some fertiliser/compost to the soil especially if you haven't  for 2 years. As that might also be contributing to the damage as well